# Looking for Uehara, Massey article

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this kind of a question. But I cannot find the following article:

Uehara, Hiroshi; Massey, W.S. The Jacobi identity for Whitehead products.
Algebraic geometry and topology. A symposium in honor of S. Lefschetz, pp. 361-377. Princeton University Press, Princeton, N.J., (1957).

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: The book in question should be available in various libraries. It can also be bought at a quite reasonable price: http://press.princeton.edu/titles/6452.html It is not quite clear what exact help you seek.

Comment: (Unfortunately we cannot permit links to so-called "pirate book sites".)

Comment: The book is available here: http://libgen.io/book/index.php?md5=7A35D6CA5CEDE8CD7152C0941AD6C302